Adam and Eve's Children and the tree of life
Were Adam and eve the only exiles from Eden in Genesis 3:21-24, because only Adam and Eve were refrained from eating of the tree of life in Genesis 3:21-24? Is there anything in Genesis 1-3 that indicates there might have been others (children of Adam and Eve) that might have remained?

The text indicates that Adam and Eve's children were not born until after their parents had been expelled:

[Gen. 3] 23 The Lord God therefore banished him from the garden of
Eden, to till the ground from which he had been taken. 24 He expelled
the man, stationing the cherubim and the fiery revolving sword east of
the garden of Eden, to guard the way to the tree of life. [Gen. 4] 1
The man had intercourse with his wife Eve, and she conceived and gave
birth to Cain, saying, “I have produced a male child with the help of
the Lord.”[a] 2 Next she gave birth to his brother Abel.

Therefore, only Adam and Eve were exiled from Eden. However, the guardians who prevented them from re-entering and partaking of the Tree of Life are presumed to prevent their descendants from entering as well. So we may count all mankind as exiles. Various mystical traditions hold that the Edenic state and the Tree of Life are available to Adam and Eve's descendants, but this is not indicated in the text itself.

Does it say that Adam and Eve bore no children while in the garden? I think there is an argument that not many realize with this one.

Cain is named as the firstborn child of Adam and Eve. He then murdered his brother Abel. The Genesis account shows that a good many years had passed before that murder took place. They were grown up enough to be able to select from the work of their hands what they would personally sacrifice to God. They were not children. "And in process of time" Genesis 4:3 states, the murder happened. A point showing that they had to be outside of Eden was that there was no need for sacrifices to God until after sin had entered in. Both sons and their parents were outside of Eden. Then, at 130 years of age, we are told that Adam  fathered Seth (Genesis 5:3). In the New Testament, the genealogical line of descent from Jesus goes back to Seth, this third named son of Adam (Luke 3:38).
The Bible places incredible importance in tracing ancestry and in naming (in particular) first-born sons. That is why the Genesis genealogies are significant when answering this question. Three sons of Adam and Eve are named, whereas their other sons and daughters are not. The first son was banished and must have taken to wife a very close relative. The second son was murdered before fathering children (otherwise, there would have been mention of that), and the third son went on to be a forebear of Jesus Christ.
Genesis gives the order of events: God cast the first couple out of Eden, then Adam knew his wife Eve who bore their son, Cain, then Abel. After Abel's murder, a third son named Seth was born to them. Had there been a child (or children) born to the couple while they were in Eden, the inspired account would never have kept that a secret. Nor could it go on to speak of sin entering the world through Adam, and thus in sin spreading to "all men because they had all sinned" (Romans 5:12). All the children of Adam and Eve were born after sin had entered the world.
The answer is, "No, there is no indication in Genesis chapter 1 to 3 - or anywhere else in the Bible - that there might have been other children of Adam and Eve that might have remained in Eden." That is why Geneses clearly names the two who were expelled from Eden, who then went on to have children. Had they had a child or children who remained sinless and so were allowed to remain in Eden, then Eden would have continued to exist. The onus is on those believing that to then point to where Eden presently is, for if anyone remained in it without sinning, they would keep on living.
For anyone to claim that the Bible needs to say Adam and Eve bore no children while in the garden is to invent an argument from silence, whereas everything in the Bible upholds the order of events given in Genesis, and names all the names that are essential to showing how Jesus was a descendant from the third son, Seth.

Where does it say that there was no need for sacrifices or offerings in the garden? Maybe not sin sacrifices, but first fruits from keeping the garden? It never says there weren't, yet you say there weren't.  Why are you looking at chapter 4 as a continuation of chapter 3? Genesis is not an order of events. If it is, the author is senile. I will disagree that there is no indications about children in the garden. There is plenty if you see what it's actually saying. Your view is a traditional view that has never worked (no offense). Too many unanswered questions making it likely false.

@Biff  No offense taken. You clearly have made your mind up already, on this matter, so I will leave you to your convictions, knowing that my decision not to respond to your further questions will cause you no offense either.

Look at these passages and you tell me where Cain was.
first verses involve the cursing


Now you are under a curse - Cain
Cursed is the ground because of you - Adam


second verses involve consequence


You will be driven from the ground - Cain
So the Lord God banished him from the Garden of Eden - Adam


third verses involve ability to be fruitful


When you work the ground, it will no longer yield its crops for you. - Cain
Through painful toil you will eat food from the cursed ground all the days of your life. It will produce thorns and thistles for you. - Adam


fourth verses involve being removed from God's presence


So he went out from the Lord’s presence east of Eden. - Cain
After he drove the man out, he placed on the east side of the Garden of Eden... - Adam


These verses are 2 different accounts. The verses numbered with 1 are about Cain. The verses numbered with 2 are about Adam.
There is no text that directly says that Adam and Eve had children before they were removed. However, there are also no texts saying that they did not have children before they were removed. So either way is speculation. Why is it acceptable to speculate that they didn't, but unacceptable to speculate that they did?
When God pronounces Eve's future outside the garden, he declares Gen 3:16, "I will make your pains in childbearing very severe; with painful labor you will give birth to children. Your desire will be for your husband, and he will rule over you.”
God tells Eve that outside his safe space is turmoil. He does not tell her that she will begin to produce humans for the first time, but rather that her experience with producing children will involve struggle outside the garden. This is how she bears fruit. So to the serpent, he will seek to devour people, Adam will struggle to bear fruit that comes from working the ground, Eve will struggle as well. Are we to assume that Adam did not work to keep the garden, and never produced fruit while in the garden also? Of course everything Adam did was blessed while in the garden. Everything Eve did was blessed while in the garden. Both produced fruit.
Genesis 2:15 - The Lord God took the man and put him in the Garden of Eden to work it and take care of it.
Adam produced fruit from his work while in the garden. Then it is only consistent that Eve also produced fruit in the garden.
Genesis 2:24 That is why a man leaves his father and mother and is united to his wife, and they become one flesh.
How does a man and woman become one flesh? Isn't this by consummation?
The accounts of Genesis 1,2,3,4 are not telling us of a chronological order of events, but of separate accounts.
Genesis 4 may in fact be starting from inside the garden.
Gen 4:11 -  Now you are under a curse and driven from the ground, which opened its mouth to receive your brother’s blood from your hand.
What ground is Cain being driven from? The camp of Adam? It doesn't say that.
Blood calling from the ground implies sacred ground.
Genesis 4:12 - When you work the ground, it will no longer yield its crops for you.
This is apparent that Cain was in the garden where the ground yields its crops. It's the same response that God gave to Adam previously.
This also makes sense that the declaration that God gave to Cain was much later than when God gave it to Adam upon his removal. By this time, Adam and Eve probably had multiple children outside the garden. This is in context with verse 14
Gen 4:14 - Today you are driving me from the land, and I will be hidden from your presence; I will be a restless wanderer on the earth, and whoever finds me will kill me.”

The presence of God is in the garden
Being outside the garden is being hidden from God
There are people outside the garden already who will want to kill Cain.

This is only possible if Adam and Eve had children outside already.
Cain and Abel did not sin by eating the fruit from the tree of knowledge so they were allowed to remain. Yet when Cain killed Abel, righteous blood cried from the ground accusing Cain. He was forced to leave the garden leaving the garden empty
Gen 4:16 - So Cain went out from the Lord’s presence east of Eden.
Just like Adam, Cain has to exit and go east.
Gen 3:24 - After he drove the man out, he placed on the east side of the Garden of Eden cherubim and a flaming sword flashing back and forth to guard the way to the tree of life.
This verse shows the flaming sword guarding the way to the tree of life from those outside the garden. But for Cain and Abel, they are not coming from the outside. They are not cut off from the tree of life. Matter of fact, Abel is the only human to have never been removed from the garden, or be cut off from the tree of life. Righteous Abel.
