Did Eve have a girl child or girl children before the birth of Cain?
We see how Eve is cursed for her disobedience, in Gen 3:16( NIV):

He told the woman,“I’ll greatly increase the pain of your labor during childbirth.
It will be painful for you to bear children,

Going further to Gen 4:1, we read :

Now Adam knew Eve his wife, and she conceived and bore Cain, and said, “I have acquired a man from the Lord.”.

Now, the words ' greatly increase ' imply that Eve had already given birth to a child or children before she committed the sin of disobedience. Gen 4:1 suggests that Eve already had a girl child/ children before the birth of Cain, the 'man'.My question therefore is : Did Eve have a girl child or girl children before the birth of Cain ?

This question rang a bell in my memory and, right enough, I'd answered a very similar one quite recently. It is not included in the "Related" questions on the left-hand-side here. Strange. Here is the link, https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/98960/adam-and-eves-children-and-the-tree-of-life

And a good answer, @Anne. Thanks for providing the link.

This question is similar to: Adam and Eve's Children and the tree of life. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Nijel J, the question you have quoted is based on speculation whereas my question is based on two Verses from Genesis which need interpretation. The  time gap between God's commandment, the disobedience of Adam and Eve, the punishment they get, and their expulsion from Eden - is not told in Genesis. For example,  Adam had been told that he would die if he ate the fruit, but lived upto 930 years ! Genesis does not say that he was caught ' red- handed' .

And I am thankful to see that the answers posted so far directly address my question . Please don't let waking questions sleep.

Gen1:28 -  God blessed them and said to them, “Be fruitful and increase in number; fill the earth and subdue it. This command was given on the 6th day. The fall occurred on the 7th day according to Jesus in Mt 12:11 - “What man is there among you who has one sheep, and if it falls into a pit on the Sabbath, will not lay hold of it and lift it out?" So this does imply that Eve did give birth in the garden since her "bearing fruit" comes by way of producing offspring, even before the fall. It is a mistake to say that Gen 4 "knew" says anything about being the first.

Thanks, Biff. In Mtt 12:11, Jesus was correcting the Pharisees on their scrupulous observance of Sabbath ignoring compassion. It can't be seen as an indicator of the day on which the first parents sinned

The text indicates the first instance of Eve's bearing a child in Gen. 4:1, as the OP mentions. There is no mention of any earlier children born to Eve. Genesis 5:4 mentions daughters, but in this genealogy they come after the birth of Seth.

3 Adam was one hundred and thirty years old when he begot a son in his
likeness, after his image; and he named him Seth. 4 Adam lived eight
hundred years after he begot Seth, and he had other sons and
daughters. 5 The whole lifetime of Adam was nine hundred and thirty
years; then he died.

Regarding "I will increase the pain of your labor during childbirth," this does not imply previous births. Rather it is generally understood to mean that this pain would be increased compared to the hypothetical situation in which Eve had not disobeyed God's commandment.
Conclusion: A "yes" answer to the OP's question would be based on speculation. There is indeed a rabbinical tradition that Adam had a previous wife, Lilith, who gave birth to various evil spirits. However, the idea that Eve had previous children is novel, as far as I know.

Can you interpret Genesis 1:28? God blessed them and said to them, “Be fruitful and increase in number; fill the earth and subdue it. This command was given before the fall.

Do the words ' greatly increase ' imply that Eve had already given birth to a child or children before she committed the sin of disobedience?
NO!

No Old and New Testament scripture teaches that Eve had a child or children before the fall.

No historical evidence of a child or children born before the fall.

Only two people were mentioned to have been driven out of the garden after the fall. This was the best opportunity to tell us who was left behind.

No evidence exists that anyone ate out of the Tree of Life before the fall.

If Eve had a child or children before the fall, there would have been people without sinful nature in the world. Rom. 5:12

Look at this verse:

“Nevertheless death reigned from Adam to Moses, even over them that had not sinned after the similitude of Adam's transgression, who is the figure of him that was to come.” (Rom 5:14, KJV)



"Death reigned from Adam....." No one was excluded from the loins of Adam.

If Eve had a child or children before the fall, the death of Christ would excluded from the benefit of the atonement for they were conceived before Adam's disobedience.
If Eve had a child or children before the fall the wrath of God would have been excluded from them because they did not sin in Adam.

Hence, Eve did not have a child before the fall.
Did Eve have, at least, a girl child before Cain was born?
Highly probable!

“And Adam knew Eve his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and said, I have gotten a man from the LORD.” (Gen 4:1, KJV)

The key to the probability is "...I HAVE GOTTEN..."

It implies that Eve was having something different from a man-child.
It also implies that Eve was probably not satisfied with what she
had until she got a man-child.
It implies that she was expecting a man-child so much that she could not hide the excitement by saying "...I have gotten a man..."

Hence, the probability that Eve had a girl or girls before Cain was born is high. We must note that no scriptures teach that as well. We know that Adam had male and female. Gen.5:4. Adam lived for 930 years. Gen.5:5
However, Cain could only have married one of his sisters. Gen 4:17. Adam was the first man. 1 Cor.15:45. There were no beings outside of Adam.

Thanks, Boavinture Ferreira.  The name Cain comes from the Hebrew word Qayin, which is derived from the verb kinyan, meaning "acquisition". In the Bible, Cain is the firstborn son of Adam and Eve. One theory is that Eve named Cain after the verb kana (קנה‎ qnh), which means "to get". In Genesis 4:1, Eve says, "I have gotten a man from the Lord" after giving birth to Cain.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - The text never states when and where Cain was birthed. Chapter 4 is not a continuation of chapter 3. Chapter 2 does not chronologically follow chapter 1. Chapter 3 does not follow chapter 2. Chapter 4 does not follow chapter 3. So reading these chapters as a continuation of events is a problem since they are separate accounts. To read it as if Cain was born outside the garden is speculation that leads to too many unanswerable questions. Looking at chapter 4 and the similarities between what God says to Adam, and what God says to Cain leaves the idea of the garden.
